# iMessage User "is not registered with iMessage"

Tags: messages, sms

Recently bought an iPhone 5 & iPad Mini.  Today tried to message a non-iphone user and got a red name icon in the addressee box that came up as "...is not registered with iMessage" that came up" with an option to "Remove".  Did a little web search and discovered that the Mini iMessage" option page in Settings does not show a toggle for "Send as SMS". My new and older iPhones do have that option and don't show the error message..even when I turn that toggle off.  I called Apple Help and was told that there is a fix for it, but that I would have to purchase a three month version of Apple Care for them to address it.  I really love my new Mini, but at $600+ if they won't fix a basic function, it's headed right back to the store.
Any help would be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Are you using a Wifi only or 4G iPad Mini?

Comment: I have the wifi-cellular on AT&T with 4G LTE

Comment: See my comments on Bill's answer - you can always get self help online on in an Apple Retail store, but devices without cellular chips don't send SMS. Hardware support is one year but it doesn't seem that's the issue here.

Comment: I was trying to avoid going to the Apple store on a pre-xmas weekend, but guess I'll have to try. I am still confused.  I have the cellular model which is definitely working, all of which says it has the chip it needs.  Don't understand why it would thus be different from the phone.  Are you saying ipads even with cellular connections still can't send SMS?  Or are you saying iMessage on iPads in general can't send SMS?

Comment: @user37120 iPad's in general cannot send SMS or make calls. It's not designed for that.

Answer (score 1):

Messages on an iPad can't send an SMS so you can't send a message to a non-Apple phone. You'll need an SMS apple like Google Voice for that.

There Shouldn't be any problem sending an SMS from Messages on the iPhone though.

I've never heard of a three month version of AppleCare but both the iPad Mini and iPhone 5 come with 90 days of free phone support and a year warranty so I don't know why Apple would want you to buy anything.

Comment: Bill - Technically AppleCare is all customer support within Apple - whether you are in the genius bar, reading apple.com/support or on the telephone. Even authorized service partners are part of AppleCare when it comes to supporting Apple products. You are correct that once the free support runs out, people are asked to pay so perhaps the OP heard that they had one incident and were being advised that in using it they would have to pay for future calls...